# How to hide navigation bar on link click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 buttons and a responsive hamburger menu. Everything works as expected, but I can't think of a way to make a navigation bar go away as soon as I click on a button.
The program is supposed to work like this: clicking hamburger menu activates 3 buttons, whenever user clicks on any of those 3 buttons it hides the buttons and only leaves the button that was clicked.

This is the wanted outcome:

[image]

This is my code so far.

html:

```
<div class="selectSection">
  <button type="button" data-number="1" class="active">1</button>
  <button type="button" data-number="2">2</button>
  <button type="button" data-number="3">3</button>
</div>

<div class="hamburger">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="content" data-number="1">
    <p>1st page</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" data-number="2">
    <p>2nd page</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" data-number="3">
    <p>3rd page</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.content:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  color: orange !important;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 7;
  }

  .hamburger .line {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: black;
    margin: 6px 0px;
  }

  .selectSection {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .selectSection.active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

js

```
// change active class, show the clicked element only and hide the others

// grab all the buttons
let Buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".selectSection button");

// loop through the buttons using for..of
for (let button of Buttons) {
  // listen for a click event
  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // et = event target
    const et = e.target;
    // slect active class
    const active = document.querySelector(".active");
    // check for the button that has active class and remove it
    if (active) {
      active.classList.remove("active");
    }
    // add active class to the clicked element
    et.classList.add("active");

    // select all classes with the name content
    let allContent = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

    // loop through all content classes
    for (let content of allContent) {
      // display the content if the class has the same data-attribute as the button
      if (
        content.getAttribute("data-number") ===
        button.getAttribute("data-number")
      ) {
        content.style.display = "block";
      }
      // if it's not equal then hide it.
      else {
        content.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
}

hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
hamburger.onclick = function () {
  navBar = document.querySelector(".selectSection");
  navBar.classList.toggle("activate");
};
```

This is the demo:

https://codepen.io/f4kermak3r/pen/ExRPKzJ

Comment: Hi, in your demo the hamburguer menu does not show up. With "make a navigation bar go away as soon as I click on a link" do you mean to hide the buttons "1", "2" and "3"?

Comment: What do you mean >navigation bar go away as soon as I click on a link?

Comment: Sorry for poor explanation. Yes, I'm trying to implement a function so that if I press on 1, 2 or 3 it would hide the buttons.

EDIT: I've fixed demo - you need to change resolution to be able to see hamburger menu.

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong css class in your js file. At line 44, you must change navBar.classList.toggle("activate") to navBar.classList.toggle("active"). That should work.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it. But the main problem still exists - program is supposed to work like this: clicking hamburger menu activates 3 buttons, whenever user clicks on any of those 3 buttons it hides the buttons and only leaves the button that was clicked. Right now if I press on any of these 3 buttons it just makes them active.

Comment: You can add a 'display: none' to .selectSection button, and 'display-block' to .selectSection button.active. But i'm not sure about your explanation, because if you hide the other buttons, you won't be able to click them after that.

Comment: That's actually what I need. User needs to see the chosen button. If user needs to switch to another button, he would basically click on hamburger menu and choose another button. It's just that I can't think of a way to implement that right.

Comment: i think i can make it pure css :)